# Material UI V5 theme how to set defaultProps with breakpoints

Tags: material-ui, themes, breakpoints

Is there a way to set `defaultProps` in Material UI V5 Theme using breakpoints?
Currently I have implemented something like

```
const MuiComponent = ({ breakpoints }: Theme) => ({
styleOverrides: {
   ...
},
defaultProps: {
  [breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
    prop: prop,
  },
},
});
```

but it shows error in console log `Warning: Invalid attribute name: '@media (max-width:599.95px)'`